# Missing Date Range Dimension

Tags: looker-studio

One of my reports doesn't have the option to add a date range dimension for any chart that I use. Is this some sort of bug?

[image]

I have another similar report and it shows date range dimension. Please check below.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have several date columns in the data source but do not see the date range dimension selector for the graph/table, it is probably because the data source in question has enforced the date range filter to apply to the partitioned column.

You can check and fix this by editing the data source -> Edit connection, and check if the

> Use xxx as date range dimension

setting is on. Set it to off and then you can select the date column the date range filter applies for each graph.

Comment: I don't see this option in the 'Edit Connection' screen, could you provide clarification? cheers

Comment: I can't see this option either. However, I'm using a community connector, and apparently setting `config.setDateRangeRequired(false)` will make the data range dimension appear.

Answer (score 1):

When using certain connectors such as Google Sheets, BigQuery, etc, the Date Range Dimension is explicitly stated, thus allowing users to choose the Date Range Dimension (useful in cases where there are a number of different Date Fields).

When using connectors such as Google Analytics, Google Ads, etc, the Date Range Dimension is automatically detected, selected, applied, and is implicitly stated; One way to manually select a Date Range Dimension on these Data Sources is to create a [Data Extract](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9019969).

Answer (score -1):

In your Connector Script (google app script), set the config like this.

```
function getConfig() {
  return {
    dateRangeRequired: false
  };
}
```

For me, I set the `date range required` to FALSE and the `date range dimension` section appears in GDS.

Comment: **NOTE**: The queston is about Looker Studio (formerly known as Google Data Studio), which is primarily web based and is no-code, thus it's unclear exactly what the suggestion is and where the suggested code is meant to be added. Is it meant to be part of a community visualisation?